# Laravel 5.5 - Method [validationRequired] does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I have a very weird problem. When I'm submitting the form, it throws an error with server-side validation.

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method [validationRequired] does not exist.

My controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'DateDebut' => 'required',
        'TimeDebut' => 'required',
    );

    $messages = [
        'DateDebut.required'=>'La date de début de réunion est obligatoire.',
        'TimeDebut.required'=>'L\'heure de début de réunion est obligatoire.'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('demandes.create')
            ->withErrors($validator->errors()->messages());
    } else {
        return view('demandes.index');
    }
}
```

The controller fails on the methode `$validator->fails()`

Comment: Try to look into the value of `$validator` with this `dd($validator)`, you can also check the values you pass to the validator this way to see if you notice anything off. 
Last thing to check is if you have the correct `Validator` in your code

Comment: can you give web.php

Comment: `dd($validator')` return a Validator object with all my data and all the rules . For the class `Validator` it call the interface of laravel framework with `use Validator` on the top of the controller.

@ArijitJana what did you expect when you said "web.php" ?

Comment: I mean to say your web.php file in your routes folder @Damien Madaule

Comment: I can't publish all the web.php file but for this controller a use this part of the file :
`Route::resource('demandes', 'RequestController');`

Comment: you can try this: Route::resource('demandes', 'RequestController', [
    'only' => ['store']
]);

Comment: It's don't work because I have other methode ( like create or show) in this controller and if I use atribut "only" the orthers routes wasn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
return redirect()->route('demandes.create')
            ->withErrors($validator->errors()->messages());
```

To this

```
return redirect()->route('demandes.create')
                ->withErrors($validator->errors()->toArray());
```